# How to declare global variables in wdio.conf.js file and use into test files?? e.g UserName, Password, DOB, Contact etc

Tags: javascript, wdio

I want to use global variables declared in wdio.conf.js file into my test files. in below test I am using UserName, Password, PageTile. I want to use them via wdio.conf.js file globaly??

```
describe('My Store|Automationpractice.com', () => {

it('should go to url and login with valid credentials', async () => {

   
    await LoginPage.open();
    await expect(browser).toHaveTitle('My Store');
    await LoginPage.signInbtn.click();
    await expect(browser).toHaveTitle('Login - My Store');
    await LoginPage.login('UserName','Password');
    await expect(browser).toHaveTitle('My account - My Store');
    await browser.pause(5000);
});
```

Comment: `"I want to use global variables"`. Global variables should only be used if you know exactly what you are doing, and perhaps not even then. Avoid global variables as much as you possibly can. Global constants are fine, but global variables are evil.

Comment: either global variable or global constant, I want to know how I can declare them in config file and use in test file?

Comment: You have not shown us what your wdio.conf.js file looks like, but surely you can just import it and use the relevant constants without any additional work?